# haskell - turning list of lists into one list

Tags: list, function, haskell

If I have a list of lists, say `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`, is there any way in Haskell to turn this into just 1 list, like `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Concat does what you'd like:

```
concat [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

To find these sorts of functions in the future, you can use hoogle http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/

You can search for a type - your required function is `[[Int]] -> [Int]`, so you could do [this search](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5b%5bInt%5d%5d+-%3E+%5bInt%5d). The top function is concat.

I should mention that in fact

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

So it works on any list of lists, and you could also quite happily search 
hoogle with that type instead. Hoogle's smart enough to understand 
which types are appropriately close to what you asked for, though.

Answer (score 8):

There are some ways to do it, you can use list comprehensions, for example:

```
[y | x <- [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], y <- x]
```

or join function, that, actually, same way:

```
import Control.Monad (join)
join [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

or concat function:

```
concat [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

or msum (same with concat):

```
import Control.Monad (msum)
msum [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

or mconcat (same with concat):

```
import Data.Monoid (mconcat)
mconcat [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really useful to see the different ways you can do one thing! :)

Answer (score 5):

Direct Answer

```
> concat [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

You should try [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5B%5Ba%5D%5D%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D) whenever you want to search for any function. Sometimes type is enough to get information about a function you need.